# Nginx Reverse Proxy with multiple servers

Tags: nginx

Here is my situation: I will have one server running nginx, and two servers  running apache + tomcat

I am NOT trying to do any load balancing.

What I need to do is setup nginx to proxy connections to specific servers based on the url. (in Local network)

IE, @IP_of_nginx:4444 should point to server apache , @IP_of_nginx:5555 should point to tomcat server.

I am not that familiar with nginx, but I could not find a specific configuration online that fit my situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Similar config to this should work:

```
server {
  listen      4444;
  charset     utf-8;
  server_name _;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://apache:80;
  }
}
server {
   listen     5555;
   charset     utf-8;
   server_name _;
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://tomcat:8080;
   }
}
```